# No vbox guest modules load in Debian guest after update Virtualbox from v6 to v7

Tags: virtualbox, virtualbox-guest-additions

After updated Virtualbox from v6 to v7 on Window 10 - I installed extension pack for v7 and then reinstalled guest additions for the guest.
The guest is Debian with kernel 4.9. I have also installed the headers for the kernel.

However - the resolution do not change when I resize the window. I saw that no `vboxdrv` exists and when I try to see the modules loaded - I get this:

```
$> lsmod | grep vbox
vboxguest             256962  2
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Comment: I know it's not a programming Q&A 100%, but I also saw other questions for Virtualbox and other related virtualization stuff, so I thought it won't be a problem to post the question here!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with the variant to create a new VM and `scp` everything from the "broken" one. So I created the same VM - AntiX - and installed guest additions - and all worked as expected - I was able to change screen resolution.

However, I noticed that the kernel on the new VM is 5.10, while on the "broken" one was 4.9. So - I upgraded the kernel of the broken one - and voila! - I got the guest additions to work again :)